# Count of Rownumber before a particular value

Tags: sql

Suppose I have the following table. I want to count the number of wins before the first loss and I want to order by day. So before first loss on 4th Jan, there were 3 wins on 1st, 2nd and 3rd I should get 3. I used a case statement within rownumber (), but didn't work

```
Day Score 
2-Jan   Win
1-Jan   Win
4-Jan   Lose
3-Jan   Win
5-Jan   Lose
6-Jan   Win
```

Desired Output

```
Day   Count(wins)
Day 3-Jan 3
```

Comment: please show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select max(date), count(*)
from t
where t.score = 'Win' and
      t.date < (select min(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.score = 'Lose');
```

Comment: how do I scale this for future months like feb and march? the inner subquery only returns one value. Can't do this for multiple values

Comment: :@gordon-linoff any suggestions on this would be appreciated

Comment: @KiranK . . . I don't see anything in the question that is related to month.  I would suggest you ask another question, including sample data and desired results.